# What does hh23 mean on oracle

Tags: oracle, date, to-char

I read a lot of tutorial which uses hh23 and hh24 interchangeably. to do to_char on oracle. Is the hh23 a legacy syntax? I tried doing it on simple query and it causes an error.

> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh23'), to_char(sysdate, 'hh24') from dual

I'm trying to find a reference to this but there is none. Or is the tutorial just written wrong? For example on http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055.

Comment: It is a typo, as discussed in the thread you link to.

Comment: 24 hour format, so 2pm would be 12+2=14.  HH12 would have 2pm as 02, which means you'd need the AM/PM part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a typo.

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh23:mi:ss') from dual
  2  /
select to_char(sysdate, 'hh23:mi:ss') from dual
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized


SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') from dual
  2  /

TO_CHAR(
--------
11:25:21

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is just a typing error in untested code.  'hh23' will always give an error.

Comment: @APC: Tom Kyte was replaced by a committee of untested pre-alpha AI servers several years ago, so no worries. :-)